# Trying to wrap std containers to store rvalue references (like unique_ptr, but on the stack)

Tags: c++, templates, std, unique-ptr, rvalue

I'm trying to do strange things again.

Okay, here's the general idea. I want a `std::list` (and `vector` and so on) that actually own the objects they contain. I want to **move** the values into it, and access them by reference.

Example using a list of unique_ptr:

```
using namespace std;
list<unique_ptr<T>> items;     // T is whatever type
items.push_back(make_unique(...));
items.push_back(make_unique(...));

for ( unique_ptr<T> item : items )
    item.dosomething();
```

With me so far? Good. Now, let's do it with stack semantics and rvalue references. We can't just use a `list<T&&>` for obvious reasons, so we'd have to make a new class:

```
using namespace std;
owninglist<T> items;
items.push_back(T());
items.push_back(T());

for ( T& item : items )
    item.dosomething();
```

Of course, I might want an `owningstack` or `owningvector` as well, so ideally we want it to be templated:

```
owning<std::list<T>> items;
```

The `owning<U<T>>` class should inherit whatever `push_back()` and `pop_front()` etc functions the underlying collection has. Presumably to achieve that, I'd need to code a generic base class, and derive explicit specialisations for the collections that have unusual functions:

```
template<typename T> owning<std::queue<T>> : owningbase<T> {
    void push_front() { ... }
}
```

I'm getting stuck on the iterators. The `begin()` and `end()` functions should return an iterator that works the same as the underlying collection's iterator would, except with an `operator*()` that returns the item by **lvalue** reference instead of by value.

We'd need some way to transfer ownership of an item out of the list again. Perhaps the iterator could have an `operator~` that returns the item as an **rvalue**, deletes the item from the list, and invalidates the iterator?

Of course, all this is assuming the underlying `std::list` (or whatever) can be convinced to take an rvalue. If `push_back()` copies the value in as an lvalue, then none of this is going to work. Would I be better off coding a container from scratch? If I did, is there some way to put the majority of the code for `list`, `queue`, `stack` and `vector` into a single base class, to save rewriting pretty much the same class four times over?

Perhaps I could introduce an intermediate class, some kind of wrapper? So `owned<list<T>>` could inherit from `list<refwrapper<T>>` or something? I know boost has a `reference_wrapper`, but I'm not sure it fits this scenario.

Comment: What's wrong with `list<T>`?

Comment: Perfect example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve with this container?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want: "I want to move the values into it, and access them by reference." This **is** what you're doing with a Standard Library container (if you use an prvalue or `move` to store the elements with `push_back`).

Comment: @DyP: I didn't know `push_back()` had an overload for rvalues. I'm an idiot.

Comment: @GManNickG: Adding a bunch of noncopyable objects to a list, and having the list "own" them. As DvP said, the containers *already* support this. \*Facepalm\*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid copy elements around you can use std::move.

So if you have a std::list you can populate it with values by moving them in:

```
SomeBigObject sbo;

std::list<SomeBigObject> list;
list.push_back(SomeBigObject()); // SomeBigObject() is a rvalue and so it is moved
list.push_back(std::move(sbo));  // sbo may not be a rvalue so you have to move it

// For construction you can also use std::list::emplace
list.emplace(list.end());        // construct the value directly at the end of the list
```

For accessing them you can simply use the ranged based loop:

```
for(auto& i :list)
    ...
```

If you want to move them out of the container you can also use std::move.
The object is moved out of the container but the remains will still be in the container,
so you have to erase them:

```
for(auto it = list.begin; it != lsit.end();)
{
    // the value of *it is moved into obj;
    // an empty value of "SomeBigObject" will remain so erase it from the list
    SomeBigObject obj = std::move(*it);

    it = list.erase(it);

    // do something with "obj"
    ...
}
```

Comment: `for(auto& i :list)` - I did not know that I could do this. Although, thinking about it, I guess it should've been obvious. Thanks.

Comment: You can do `it = list.erase(it)` as well? That's a useful tip.

Comment: you can also use `std::list<std::reference_wrapper<SomeBigObject>>` and push like this: `list.push_back(std::ref(sbo))`, or when you work with const objects you do like this: `list.push_back(std::cref(csbo))`.